# Is it possible to write SRIOV miniport driver using WDM?

Tags: windows, driver, virtualization

I have a driver written using WDM(Windows Driver Model).
I need to add SR-IOV support to the driver.
Is it possible to write SR-IOV miniport driver using WDM or is it can be done only for WDF(Windows Driver Framework)?

Thanks
Venkatesh

Answer (score 0):

`WDF` provides a strict subset of `WDM` functionality, ergo everything writable under WDF can be written as WDM.